# C# Console - User inputs X numbers and gets stored in array

Tags: c#, arrays, console, user-input

I tried to have a console app that takes 5 numbers and fills an array with it but The issue with this code is that, it only accepts 4 numbers and fills the last index with null, how could I fix that?

```
      string[] numbers = new string[4];

        Console.WriteLine("Hi, Enter 5 numbers!");
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            string _val = "";
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                {
                    double val = 0;
                    bool _x = double.TryParse(key.KeyChar.ToString(), out val);
                    if (_x)
                    {
                        _val += key.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && _val.Length > 0)
                    {
                        _val = _val.Substring(0, (_val.Length - 1));
                        Console.Write("\b \b");
                    }
                }                  
            }
            while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
            Console.WriteLine();

            numbers[i] = _val;

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(i + " : " + numbers[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Length);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: you say you want 5 numbers, but you declare an array with 4 numbers? `new string[4]`

Comment: don't arrays start from 0? first number 0, then 1 then ...

Comment: Yes, arrays start with zero, you specify the **length** when creating it. So for an array with length 4 the valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code string[] numbers = new string[4]; means numbers array size is 4 and array starts with 0 index. Hence last index is not null. Change the string[4] to string[5]. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: as I mentioned above, don't arrays start from 0? so numbers[4] can store 5 strings Edit : well I'm dumb, I got it now